# My soft cookies are falling apart!

Tags: cookies

At my job we bake 3oz chocolate chip, peanut butter and oatmeal raisin cookies from scratch. I've been baking them to be soft on the inside and crispier on the outer edges but these cookies end up being pretty fragile. The way they display the cookies might be part of the issue (they stack them on top of each other so the top cookies end up collapsing on top of the bottom cookies) but even still when you go to grab them they easily fall apart. Mostly the oatmeal and the peanut butter ones. I was wondering what might be the cause of this and if anyone has any tips on preventing this! Thank you so much!

~Rianne

Comment: We need a rough recipe for this. Especially describe what you do to *bake them to be soft on the inside and crispier on the outer edges*

Answer (score 1):

Ok, try this: Put all of the sugar in your mixer bowl, add only 1/2 of the butter. And beat, making it as smooth as possible, add eggs, mix again, add flour and any flavoring that you use ie; vanilla, etc. Mix again, only then add the rest of the room temp soft butter. Final mix. 
   It is also possible that , in your original recipe, you were not mixing enough.
You are using a stand mixer? Right ? You might try doubling mixing time in your original recipe , AFTER you have added the flour.
I seem to recall, many, many years ago trying to make choc chip cookies at a friends house. All my friend had was a mixing bowl and a heavy wooden spoon. Those cookies fell apart after baking. Why ? My arm got too tired and I figured it was fine.  Later, at my house I made the same recipe but I used my stand mixer. Result, perfect cookies.
Good luck. Good baking

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I once had that problem on a busy day and I forgot to properly knead/blend the cookie dough. The problem is likely to be a lack of enough gluten which is the "glue" that holds bread together and makes it rise high and not spread-out.
Prior to adding your fat/butter to your cookie dough give the dough an extra few minutes of kneading/mixing, which will develop the gluten. Then, and only then, add the fat/butter. If you find that the dough is too dry (without the fat) then simply hold back some of the flour and add it near the end of mixing when you add the fat/butter
If this helps to hold your baked cookies together, fine. If not then add a few more minutes of mixing.

Comment: Hi Richard! I'm confused. What order do you add things when making cookies? Without fat/butter there is no "dough". Almost every recipe I have for cookies starts by beating butter and sugar, adding eggs and finally adding flour/leavening/flavorings. If you're recommending a different order of operations, a more detailed explanation would be appreciated. Thanks!